# Multiple sequential calls to function with callback results in callback hell

Tags: javascript, callback

I have a function that is used to communicate with a server over a TCP/IP socket. Each time it writes a command to the server it has to wait for a response. I have written a function that works fine and looks like this simplified:

```
function sendCommand(command, callback)
{
    // send command and wait for server to respond...
    // if response was ok
    callback(response, null);
    // if response was bad
    callback("", error);
}
```

The problem with this is that I want to send sequences of commands to the server and depending on what the answer is I either want to proceed with the next command or handle the error and not send any further commands.

Currently I use this function as such:

```
sendCommand("first command to server", function(response, error)
{
    if(error)
    {
        // handle error
    }
    else
    {
        sendCommand("second command to server", function(response, error)
        {
            //etc..
        }
    }
}
```

When doing many sequential calls this results in callback hell. Is there any way to make a conditional call-chain that breaks if I receive an error? something like:

```
sendCommand("command1", function(){})
.sendCommand("command2", function(){})
.sendCommand("command3", function(){})
.sendCommand("command4", function(){});
```

And for example if command2 receives an error, command3 and command4 calls are never executed.

Comment: If you mean that the second command needs to be sent after the first if successful, the third after the second if successful, etc.? If so, invoke each successive command within the success callback of the previous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to have a look at `Promises` instead of using `callbacks`:

```
function sendCommand(command) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    if(Math.random() > 0.6) {
      reject("Command " + command + " failed.");
    } else {
      resolve("Command " + command + " succeeded");
    }
  });
}

sendCommand("command1")
.then(function(data) {
  console.log(data); //Data from command1
  return sendCommand("command2");
})
.then(function(data) {
  console.log(data); //Data from command2
  return sendCommand("command3");
})
.then(function(data) {
  console.log(data); //Data from command3
  return sendCommand("command4");
})
.then(function(data) {
  console.log(data); //Data from command4
})
.catch(function(error) {
  console.log(error); //Error from any command
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Arg0n/epzw4rdm/10/)

**UPDATE 1**

Handle error different depending on which failed example:

```
function sendCommand(command) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    if(Math.random() > 0.6) {
      reject({ command: command, msg: "Command " + command + " failed."});
    } else {
      resolve("Command " + command + " succeeded");
    }
  });
}

sendCommand("command1")
.then(function(data) {
  console.log(data); //Data from command1
  return sendCommand("command2");
})
.then(function(data) {
  console.log(data); //Data from command2
  return sendCommand("command3");
})
.then(function(data) {
  console.log(data); //Data from command3
  return sendCommand("command4");
})
.then(function(data) {
  console.log(data); //Data from command4
})
.catch(function(error) {
  switch(error.command) {
    case "command1":
      //Handle command1 error
      break;
    case "command2":
      //Handle command1 error
      break;
    case "command3":
      //Handle command1 error
      break;
    case "command4":
      //Handle command1 error
      break;
  }
  console.log(error.msg); //Error message from any command
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Arg0n/epzw4rdm/11/)

Comment: How do you stop the chain in case of an error? since you don't return anything in the error function won't it crash? I guess I could return a rejected promise in the error function to stop any further commands?

Comment: Updated again, found a much cleaner way using `catch`.

Comment: That would work. However, if I want to treat error differently depending on which command returns an error I cant do it like that.

Comment: Well, you could pass something to identify which command failed in `reject`. And handle it in `catch`.